# docker flannel subnet issues

Tags: docker, coreos, flannel

> Docker not picking up flannel subnet. Any help will be greatful. I am
>   using coreos as my container Linux and docker version is 1.12.6
>      my docker startup file look like below.
>     Flannel is working as expected

```
[Unit]
 Description=Docker Application Container Engine
 Documentation=http://docs.docker.com
 After=containerd.service docker.socket network.target
 Requires=containerd.service docker.socket
 [Service]
 Type=notify
 EnvironmentFile=-/run/flannel/flannel_docker_opts.env
 # the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues 
 still
 # exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set 
 required
 # for containers run by docker
 ExecStart=/usr/lib/coreos/dockerd --host=fd:// --
 containerd=/var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock 
 $DOCKER_OPTS $DOCKER_CGROUPS $
 ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
 LimitNOFILE=1048576
 # Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting 
 overhead
 # in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local 
 accounting.
 LimitNPROC=infinity
 LimitCORE=infinity
 # Uncomment TasksMax if your systemd version supports it.
 # Only systemd 226 and above support this version.
 TasksMax=infinity
 TimeoutStartSec=0
 # set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker 
 containers
 Delegate=yes
 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
# /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/40-flannel.conf
[Unit]
Requires=flanneld.service
After=flanneld.service
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/kubernetes/cni/docker_opts_cni.env
# /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/40-storage.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --host=fd:// --graph="/abc/docker" $DOCKER_OPTS 
$DOCKER_CGROUPS $DOCKER_OPT_BIP $DOCKER_OPT_MTU $DOCKER_OPT_IPMASQ
# /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/50-insecure-registry.conf
[Service]
Environment=DOCKER_OPTS='--insecure-registry="10.x.x.x:5000"'
# /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/50-require-flannel.conf
[Unit]
Requires=flanneld.service
After=flanneld.service
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if `/run/flannel/flannel_docker_opts.env` exists and its content.
   My `/run/flannel/subnet.env` looks like:

   FLANNEL_NETWORK=10.252.0.0/16

   FLANNEL_SUBNET=10.252.127.1/24

   FLANNEL_MTU=1450

   FLANNEL_IPMASQ=false
2. Add `--bip=${FLANNEL_SUBNET} --mtu=${FLANNEL_MTU}` to dockerd args.
3. If this cannot work, `rm -rf /var/lib/docker/overlay2/*` and restart docker.service